# Magento 2.4.3 login customer without password

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3

I recently upgraded my Magento version from 2.4.2 to 2.4.3, The following code is not working properly (Session and Cookies not working) while it's working fine in the previous version:

```
protected $_customer;
protected $_customerSession;

    public function _construct(...
                             \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
                             \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession) {
        ...
        $this->_customer = $customer;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        ...
    }
    $customer = $this->_customer->loadByEmail("test@m2s.com"); 
    $this->_customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
```

When I clicked on "Proceed to checkout" button the login pop again asking for login.
While when I'm using login with password then it's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the code as follows, and it's working fine.

```
<?php

namespace Arunendra\OtpLogin\Controller\Ajax;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory;

class Userotp extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    ......
    protected $cookieMetadataManager;
    protected $cookieMetadataFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
      ......
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
   ......
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        ......
        $websiteId =$this->storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
        $customer = $this->_customer->setWebsiteId( $websiteId)->loadByEmail($isEmail['email']); 
        $this->refresh($customer);
        ......
    }
 
    /* Login otp issue*/
    public function refresh($customer)
    {

        if ($customer && $customer->getId()) {
            $this->_customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
            $this->_customerSession->regenerateId();

            if ($this->getCookieManager()->getCookie('mage-cache-sessid')) {
                $metadata = $this->getCookieMetadataFactory()->createCookieMetadata();
                $metadata->setPath('/');
                $this->getCookieManager()->deleteCookie('mage-cache-sessid', $metadata);
            }
        }
    }
      private function getCookieManager()
    {
        if (!$this->cookieMetadataManager) {
            $this->cookieMetadataManager = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                PhpCookieManager::class
            );
        }

        return $this->cookieMetadataManager;
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve cookie metadata factory
     *
     * @deprecated
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory
     */
    private function getCookieMetadataFactory()
    {
        if (!$this->cookieMetadataFactory) {
            $this->cookieMetadataFactory = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                CookieMetadataFactory::class
            );
        }

        return $this->cookieMetadataFactory;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you're executing the code, but to log in the customer and update the section data, you have to use a `POST`-request.

You saying that you click the "Proceed to checkout" button signals that you may be using a `GET`-request.

I found the demonstration in this module quite helpful when logging in a customer via email: https://github.com/flagbit/magento2-virtual-customer-session/